# Is the compound CM-7 in Red Comet fire grenades azeotropic dichloromethane?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, history-of-chemistry

Red Comet Manufacturing changed the liquid in their fire grenades from carbon tetrachloride to something they referred to as CM-7 in 1955.

Is CM-7 the same thing as azeotropic dichloromethane? If not, what is the composition of CM-7? What are the gases given off by CM-7 when it is exposed to heat?

Comment: Nope. I've run a distillation of the CM-7 fluid and I got roughly four different fractions across 50-70 C (83 kpa ambient pressure where I am). Too high to be dichloromethane or trichlorotrifluoroethane, too low to be carbon tet, if there's chloroform in there it's not much, I've trawled the internet as hard as google will allow and I can't find a good answer for what liquid I have three liters of.

Answer (score 2):

Passive fire suppression systems by Red Comet included a glass bulb with colorless transparent liquid, and had a sticker:

> MC-7 This fire extinguisher contains azeotropic chlormethanes®

Registered trademark symbol already signifies that marketing already prevailed at that time. Indeed, among chlormethanes $\ce{CH_xCl_{4-x}}$ chloromethane $\ce{CH3Cl}$ is flammable. Dichloromethane $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ is not combustible itself, but supports burning and flashes. Both chloroform $\ce{CHCl3}$ and $\ce{CCl4}$ are not flammable, but don't form azeotrope and still would produce phosgene $\ce{COCl2}$ when react with atmospheric oxygen. Also, the company denied presence of $\ce{CCl4}$ in MC-7 ([Kiplinger's Personal Finance, Oct **1956**, p. 48](https://books.google.com/books?id=GwEEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=Red+Comet+CM-7&source=bl&ots=TgPkCYgA9L&sig=0ds7soD48guF4j3-drIm5Gv_ZRY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdh_qIqpnYAhXK1qQKHe7tAP4Q6AEIXTAP#v=onepage&q=Red%20Comet%20CM-7&f=false)):

> CM-7, which has replaced carbon tetrachloride in all our grenade extinguishers. CM-7 does not produce toxic gases. It converts toxic gases created by the fire itself into additional fire-extinguishing chemicals.

As it seems like [Red Comet doesn't hold any patents for inventions in chemistry](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=pts&hl=en&q=inassignee:Red+inassignee:Comet&num=10), most likely it's a hydrochloro*fluoro*carbon that's been known at that time.

These days MC-7 extinguishers are sold as vintage items, and uniformly it's claimed (e.g. [here](https://utahtransplant.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/the-mystery-of-the-red-glass-globe/) and [there](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/t-m-red-comet-fire-ext-grenade-w-vertical)) that the liquid component is [*1,1,2-Trichloro-1,2,2-trifluoroethane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,1,2-Trichloro-1,2,2-trifluoroethane), which at that time indeed has been studied as a very unreactive (even upon heating) vaporizable liquid agent (e.g. [Fire Research Abstracts and Reviews, Vol. 3
**1961**, p. 148](https://www.nap.edu/catalog/18852/fire-research-abstracts-and-reviews-volume-3)).

Starting 1960s, several acts in Montana, Chicago, and later across US no longer permitted usage of both tetrachloromethane and MC-7 as fire-extinguishing chemicals. [Halons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_extinguisher#Halons,_Halon-replacement_clean_agents_and_carbon_dioxide) took over.